# Proper use of SOAP in Python - NULL parameter error

Tags: python, soap

Please let me know if I have some of my terminology wrong - I've been doing a lot of functional programming and not a lot of (what I consider to be) Webdev stuff.

I'm finding using SOAP in Python to be really difficult - I can't find usage examples (for syntax reference) that seem to work with the particular API I'm trying to access.  Basically, I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or if the API I'm trying to use is bugged.

What I have looks something like:

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL

server = WSDL.Proxy("https://some.example.of.a.remote.API")
results = server.MethodWithFourArguments("mike.hunt", "love", "12345", "RCP-90")

print results
```

The documentation for my remote API says that it needs the strings username, password, invoice number, and SKU number as arguments for the "MethodWithFourArguments" method.

**The problem is that I'm getting "Username was NULL" as a response back from the remote API.**

I've tried formatting the arguments as a list, as a hash, and even specifying them as utf with the little Python "u" before the string.

Am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: Don't rely on documentation. See your wsdl, your operations's request format should be different than you are providing in your code. I would suggest to use soap ui to see the request formats then form them accordingly in your python code, that would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, it turned out I needed to use the module "suds".  I was able to install it with "pip install suds", and the following is what worked:

```
import suds.client import Client

WSDL="https://some.example.of.a.remote.API"

client = Client(WSDL)
results = client.service.MethodWithFourArguments("mike.hunt", "love", "12345", "RCP-90")

print results
```

The API I'm using is very simple - I just needed to know that "SOAPpy" is deprecated and/or not working and to use "suds" instead.